# Adobe Animate (Flash): Security Sandbox Violation in Debug (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), but not Test (Ctrl+Enter)

Tags: security, actionscript-3, flash, sandbox, adobe-animate

My Flash project retrieves data from the Internet through a PHP webpage. It works fine in Adobe Animate when I Test the project with Ctrl+Enter, but when I try to Debug it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, I get a Security Sandbox Violation. I believe I have a proper crossdomain.xml file on the website, and in the Adobe Animate publish settings, Local Playback Security is set to "Access Network Only". How can I get it to work when I Debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I had to go through the Global Security Settings here:
https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html
In addition, I had to view that page with Internet Explorer 11 to be able to select local folders on my hard drive. In Chrome, I was not able to select the folders properly.